# AWS unable to connect to Java springboot API endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to run my springboot API on AWS however when i try to connect to the endpoint the error **Site cannot be reached IP refused to connect**. This my first time working with AWS.

I created a linux instance and connected to it using filezilla. Afterwards i added my jar to a folder which i created on the linux instance using filezilla. I started the springboot project and its running but the problem is that i cannt seem to connect to the endpoints. Am i missing something, how do i connect to my endpoints.

The other thing to note is that i enabled https on my API and added swagger also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable relevant ports in the instances' `Security Group`.

Look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups) to create a new Inbound rule for the specific port.
You can go to the [aws console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups:sort=groupId), (here I am assuming you have deployed to us-east-1 if its something else, go to the relevant region. 
Open up the relevant security group, and then click edit Inbound roles.

[image: Edit inbound rules]

Comment: If i enable all traffic and source set to anywhere will this be enough

Comment: myapi-env.stuffeu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/user/login thats the example url i am trying to connect with

Comment: Would recommend that you do a whats my IP search on google, that should give you the Public IP that you are using and use that in the Source, remember to give the /32 after the IP. And change the port number to whatever you are using.

Comment: So does this mean anyone who wants to connect to my api will require to provide there IP. Because different people will be connecting to this API and they are in different regions

Comment: if its supposed to be a public API, you should go in and put 0.0.0.0/0, I had assumed that its a private service that only you want to use.

Comment: Yes it is a private service but the team which works on the API they are spread across the globe

Comment: If you think the security is in place open it up to 0.0.0.0/0 and you should be good. If not you need to add a rule  for each team's public ip and then if a team's ip changes (for example for someone working from home) you need to change the rule. Basically, the realistic option is to have it open to the public with relevant security measures in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169841/discussion-between-erent-and-yogesh-d).